Maximum Number of Hops an Onion Message Can Travel?
According to the specifications: https://github.com/lightning/bolts/blob/master/04-onion-routing.md#onion-messages
What's the maximum number of hops an onion message can travel?

The specifications of BOLT04 mention that onion message packets can be either 1366 or 32834 bytes in size to keep all messages the same size for privacy. Here I want to calculate what the maximum travel distance for the larger size is.
I've found that headers are 66 bytes (version 1, public_key 33, HMAC 32) so the payload is 32834 - 66 = 32768 bytes.
OM intermediary hops payloads are at least 70 bytes (length 1, HMAC 32, type 1, subtype 1, blinded_node_id 33, enclen 2).
Hence the maximum travel distance is 32768 / 70 = 468 hops.
Are these calculations correct?
